# How to copy files from Hadoop cluster to local file system

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

### **Setup:**

I have a map-reduce job. In the mapper class (which is obviously running on the cluster), I have a code something like this:

```
try {
.
.
.
} catch (<some exception>) {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

### **What I want to change:**

In the catch{} clause, I want to copy the logs from the cluster to the local file system

### **Problem:**

I can see the log file in the directory on the node if I check from command line. But when I try to copy it use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(boolean delSrc, Path src, Path dst), it says the file does not exist.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am very new to Hadoop, so may be I am missing something obvious. Please ask ask me any clarifying questions, if needed, as I am not sure if I have given all the necessary inforation.

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**: Since I am trying to copy files from cluster to local and the java code is also running on cluster, can I even use `copyToLocalFile()`? Or do I need to do a simple `scp`?

Comment: could you show me the exception?

Comment: What command from the command line are you using to check it exists? `hadoop fs -ls ...` ?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: Yes, I am using `hadoop fs -ls` from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MapReduce log files are usually located on the data node's local file system path HADOOP_LOG_DIR/userlogs/mapOrReduceTask where the Map/Reduce program runs. Each MapReduce programs generates syslog/stdout/stderr in the above directory.

It would be easier to use the Task tracker's Web UI to see the local log files or you can ssh to the machine and look over logs in the above mentioned directories.

By default, the Task tracker Web UI URL is `http://machineName:50060/`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot use the Web UI, we have to copy the logs on local fs, that's the requirement. Apart from SSH, is there any other way to copy the logs on local from hdfs?

Comment: Hadoop logs are usually stored on the local file system. For eg, the name node may generate all the logs in nameNode machine and mapReduce tasks are still in the local file system of the machine where the MapReduce jobs ran. Since the log files are only in the local file system, you may have to use either ssh or remote login to the system and look at the files. Just to answer your question to copy a HDFS file to local system, you can use 'hadoop fs -copyToLocal <hdfsFilePath> <localFileSystemFilePath>'